# Resizing/fitting algorithm for masonry like photo display

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on an interesting project that involves displaying a large number of photos. Every single photo is a different size. I would like to resize them the least amount possible so that they fit together in a grid, some what like the [Masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin for JQuery, or [Apple's iPhoto Journals](https://www.icloud.com/journals/sample/).

Has anyone done something like this before? Any pointers on the direction I should take this? I would like to do it server-side, using Python preferably, but am really interested in figuring out the algorithm behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difficult problem.  It boils down to deciding what constraint you care most about, and sacrificing the others.  Notice for example that masonry forces everything into fixed-width columns, and iPhoto Journals are placed onto a square grid. Both sacrifice the edges of the photos for the layout of the page.

We tried a number of algorithms along these lines at Tabblo, and they all require giving up something.

HP has an algorithm called Blocked Recursive Image Composition (BRIC) that worked really well to strike a good balance.

Comment: For sure. I'm most interested in pursuing a solution like the iPhoto Journals. It looks like there is a minimum unit size, 1x1, that is used by the smallest photos. Then all other photos are fitted to this scale, 2x2, 2x3, etc.

Comment: Hmm, you also said you wanted to resize them the least amount possible.  Photos are not squares or multiples of squares, so you will be losing content at the edges.  And you still have to figure out how to fit the squares together.

Comment: Right, I'm thinking within specific regions, these 1x1 scales could have different values based on the photos that were places in that region.

Comment: Maybe the "1x1" base scale wouldn't even be 1x1! It could be something like 1x1.5, or whatever fit the other photos better.

Comment: Another thing to worry about: most photos are landscape orientation, but some will be portrait.  The two aspect ratios don't mix well.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about that. In any case, this looks like it's going to be an excellent weekend project. Thanks for the great advice.